# how get the last 4 months average value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregate-functions, mongoose-schema

I am trying this aggregation last 4 months records each month OZONE average value but average value is null how to get the average value

```
db.Air_pollution.aggregate([
 {$match:{CREATE_DATE:{$lte:new Date(),$gte:new Date(new Date().setDate(new 
   Date().getDate()-120))}}},
 {$group:{_id:{month:{$month:"$CREATE_DATE"},year:
 {$year:"$CREATE_DATE"}},avgofozone:{$avg:"$OZONE"}}},
 {$sort:{"year":-1}},{$project:
 {year:'$_id.year',month:'$_id.month',_id:0,avgofozone:1}}

])
```

output:

```
 { "avgofozone" : null, "year" : 2018, "month" : 2 }
        { "avgofozone" : null, "year" : 2018, "month" : 3 }
        { "avgofozone" : null, "year" : 2018, "month" : 1 }
```

Comment: Please post sample data set

Comment: @   Rahul Raj  "_id" : ObjectId("5ab3f0975c4f698c8a39ea22"),
    "DISTRICT" : "vskp",
    "STATION" : "appcb",
    "TAKEN_DATE" : ISODate("2018-02-25T00:18:00.000Z"),
    "OZONE" : "8:84",
    "pm10" : "69.0",
    "pm2dots" : "49.0",
    "DATA_FROM" : "vsk",
    "CREATE_DATE" : ISODate("2018-02-05T00:30:05.867Z")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because the `OZONE` field is a string, and you can't compute **`$avg`** on a string. Plus, it's not a valid number: `"8:84"` should be `8.84`

from [mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/):

> **$avg**
>
> Returns the average value of the numeric values that result from
>   applying a specified expression to each document in a group of
>   documents that share the same group by key. $avg ignores non-numeric
>   values.

Otherwise the aggregation query is correct, here is a link showing it: [mongo playground.net/p/VaL-Nn8e21E](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VaL-Nn8e21E)

Comment: @ felix ok i got it thank you

my output is:
{ "avgofozone" : 21.07777777777778, "year" : 2018, "month" : 2 }
{ "avgofozone" : 17.8, "year" : 2018, "month" : 3 }
{ "avgofozone" : 17.8, "year" : 2018, "month" : 1 }



i am expected output:

zone_type       year        january   febravary           march
avgofozone     2018         17.8      21.07777           17.8

Comment: expected output:

zone_type       year        january   febravary           march


avgofozone     2018         17.8      21.07777           17.8